# How to handle session management for application using Angular and Express

Tags: node.js, angular, express, express-session

I am using Angular4 app for UI and I have a separate Node+Express app which handles rest api calls.

Angular app runs on a different port. and express app runs on a different port.

I try to use express-session framework on the server(express)app.
I use Microsoft ADAL services to authenticate the user. After successful authentication my approach was to make a rest api call from angular app to express server app by passing userEmail and  set userEmail variable to req.session.userEmail. I expect the session to be available when a different route is being called to check if the session is available, but the session variable is always showing up as undefined.

What is the best solution here? My goal is to have a session management and prevent responding to unauthorized requests on the server side rest api calls.

Comment: Please have a look at JSON web token(JWTs) https://jwt.io/

Comment: Thanks Akkusativobjekt. It worked for me..